# NoSQL database with high read performances (write accesses are not significant)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, database, nosql

I'm working on a "real-time" website using [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/). Currently, I'm using [Redis](http://redis.io/) because I need high performance for read-access. The write accesses are not really significant for my use case.

In addition, Redis does not have a query language for the search. So, I create my indexes manually and I use some unions/intersections/... to find some values.

I think that it will be easier to use [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) with a embedded finding system and a ORM-like ([Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) for example). The problem is that I'm not sure that MongoDB is the best choice for my usecase.

What is your advices about the NoSQL DB that I need ? Redis ? [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) ? MongoDB ? [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) ? etc.

I repeat: I want to have a **real good performance for the read accesses and for the searches** (the write accesses are not significant), the simplest possible (orm-like ? finding system ? etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: The problem with your question is that it entirely depends on what kind of reads. If you're mostly joining and aggregating, for instance, your best option will be to use good old SQL with Memcached...

Comment: -2 on the question and "problem with your question" and "pointless" is a little harsh.  Wanting to know which db is best for read access speed over write is not a bad or pointless question.  A better comment would ask for the details which matter to making a decision possible, making it useful not only for Sandro but also others who are facing similar cases, by knowing which considerations matter most when making such a decision.

Comment: Thanks rossdavidh, I agree with you !

Comment: I would be very interested in this answer. +1

Comment: There is a lot that goes into answering questions like these.  Consistency of data, tolerance of data loss, # reads vs # writes, the kinds of searches done, ACID compliance requirements, etc.; these all are factors.  I honestly have to wonder about the answers to some of the questions I've seen like this because it seems the answers don't seem to address the heart of the matter but do provide some good pointers.  I'm not saying the question and answers here are bad but I've yet to be impressed with the comparisons I've seen and yet certainly each db has advantages for different scenarios.

Comment: Redis & Elasticsearch explained at infoq presentations about twitter timeline, http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Timelines-Twitter and http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Real-Time-Delivery-Twitter twitter use redis and elasticsearch for timeline architecture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that redis would be the better solution for the following reasons.

1. You require fast read access and redis provides the fastest solution since the keys are in memory, if not most.
2. Although mongodb is easier to query in the general case, your problem domain is narrow and once you decide how you would like to query the data, you can put the correct data structures and indexes in place.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Redis is a good fit for your DB, and you should look at something like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) to provide your searching.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB will do better in write heavy environment. I don't use it though.
MongoDB will do better on read heavy environment.

For search and indexing:
MongoDB would require separate index for each of your search criteria for better performance (at least this is what I remember).

Proper index is important in MongoDB. And no joins!!

Here are some links you might go through:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB

http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2009/06/29/couchdb-vs-mongodb-benchmark/

http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Hope these will help you find the right db

Goodluck